# Bean Validation and Objectify

Tags: google-app-engine, bean-validation, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I'm using Objectify to manage GAE Datastore persistence. I cannot find much useful documentation on Bean validation using Objectify. I tried using the Hibernate Validator, but it still allows me to persist invalid data. 
To make things crystal clear, here's a simple example:

```
@Entity
public class Person {
        @Id Long id;
        // validate firstName is 1-20 characters, like Hibernate's @Length(min=1, max=20) annotation 
        @Index private String firstName;

// GETTERS & SETTERS
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Some more detail information would be helpful. How are you triggering validation? Note that solely putting constraints to a Java bean doesn't automatically cause the validation, instead some code must obtain a validator and validate given objects at some point. In case of JPA this happens via an entity listener upon persisting constrained entities, I assume you could do something similar for your persistence solution.

Comment: Objectify has no built-in integration; you could file a feature request or perhaps activate it yourself in an @OnSave method.

Comment: "Note that solely putting constraints to a Java bean doesn't automatically cause the validation, instead some code must obtain a validator and validate given objects at some point"
That's exactly what I was doing wrong! Tnx guys!